# Cannot Set System Volume in iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7

In iOS 6 i get time by the following code:

```
MPMusicPlayerController *controller = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];
float volume = [controller volume];
```

In iOS 7 I cannot do like this.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MPMusicPlayerController` property volume Deprecated  in `iOS7`

```
@property(nonatomic) float volume NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(3_0, 7_0);
```